# As an atom get's bigger (on increasing atomic no.) , electrons have to move faster and faster around the nucleus, Why?

Tags: electrons, atoms, nuclear-chemistry

Does speed even make sense at such small scales ? Heisenbergs Uncertainty principle ?

Comment: It's not really the size and it's not the electrons in the outer shells that get faster. The charge of the nucleus is getting larger which means the inner electrons get closer and also faster.